# Installing Bonfire for Codeigniter Server and Install link issues

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, bonfire

I'm trying to install *Bonfire for Codeigniter* and I'm having some issues. I first tried downloading the zip, unziping it and placing it in MAMP and navigating to it through localhost. The welcome page came up but when I clicked on the "install" button, it displayed a "URL Not Found" page. Quite annoying since I'm under the gun.

I saw on youtube, that the dev team shows the install by cloning the repo on Github so I tried that next. Now when I load that in my localhost, I get a welcome page without an install button, an error saying my "htaccess" should be renamed "`.htaccess`" (although when I looked at the file it looked fine to me) but more worryingly is the next error:

> "Oops!
>   Your Web Root should be set to the public folder,but it's not. It's pointing to the Bonfire Root folder.

See below how your site should be set up on Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "[...]/htdocs/Bonfire_Root/public"
    ServerName Bonfire.Root
    ServerAlias Bonfire.Root.local
</VirtualHost>"
```

I'm a really junior programmer and I'm just trying to get this sorted out quickly because of a project I'm on that I need to turn around quickly. I'm sure this is probably something simple so does anyone know what I can do to fix this so it will work and I can begin developing with Bonfire? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

When I followed the instructions about adding my project name to the URL, I moved on to a blank page, Chrome initiated a download of a textfile called install which contains this:

> J
>   5.5.34B:;Z1&hZˇ˜Äj*/Knh@G"o/9mysql_native_password!ˇÑ#08S01Got packets out of order

I'm not sure what to do with this. Any ideas?

I've tried:

```
http://localhost/Bonfire_Root/public/

http://localhost/Bonfire_Root/public/index.php

http://192.1xx.xxx.xxx/Bonfire_Root/public/index.php
```

Each time it just downloads the textfile with the same text in it. :/

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to the issue? I'm in the same position and can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

here's my work around (I'm on linux btw):

1) make sure mod_rewrite is enable on your apache setup.

2) add `<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/your/htdocs/bonfire/public"
    ServerName bonfire.dev
    ServerAlias bonfire.dev
    <Directory "/path/to/your/htdocs/bonfire/public/">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

3) edit your /etc/hosts file, add this line 127.0.0.1 Bonfire.Root

4) restart your apache

5) access bonfire on `http://bonfire.dev`, instead of `http://localhost/Bonfire_Root/public`

hope it helps

Comment: I just tried these steps to resolve the same issue and no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest no need to use htaccess if you are working on local environment.about your error when you click on install button after that in your url put your project folder name like 'host:port/yourprojectname/public/index.php' . would redirect to you next page to get installation process done.

I had same problem but in windows yes working on mac and windows quite similar. When i clicked on install it goes to http//localhost/public which is not correct url so i have change by adding my project name after localhost  http//localhost/project/public/index.php.
Major difference between mac and window while using PHP is s you have to use ip address in place of localhost.

Comment: going to try this now.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm still having an issue though. I edited my question with the results from adding my project name to the url. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Tried it again both ways and no dice. Still downloading text files with strange stuff in them. I believe you, I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are installing bonfire in windows D:\ drive and path of you index.php is "D:/xampp/htdocs/bonfire" please follow below steps:

```
 1. Edit your `D:/xampp/htdocs/bonfire/index.php` file
```

```
    <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>

        DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/bonfire"

        ServerName 127.0.0.1

        ServerAlias bonfire.dev

    </VirtualHost>
```

2. Open your httpd.conf file (in case of xampp path will be `D:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`) and add this in the end of your file.

```
 
NameVirtualHost localhost

<VirtualHost localhost>

    DocumentRoot D:/xampp/htdocs/bonfire

    ServerName localhost

<VirtualHost>
```

`#####   
## myproject.dev   
## DOMAIN of myproject   
#####   
NameVirtualHost bonfire.dev    

<VirtualHost bonfire.dev>    
    DocumentRoot D:/xampp/htdocs/bonfire/public   
    ServerName bonfire.dev   
</VirtualHost>`

**note that bonfire.dev is a naming convention i have given to my website and mentioned it inside my `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file so as convenient to you, choose any name suitable to you**

3. Edit `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file.

Add below lines in hosts file.

`` 127.0.0.1       localhost  
    ::1             localhost  
    127.0.0.1       bonfire.dev  



4. Restart Apache and now open your web page `http://bonfire.dev/` ``

This solution works 100%, I have been fighting up with same issue and now finally its fixed. Just try it and get back to me in case of any issue.

Answer (score 1):

launches the PHP server into the directory of your project exempel

www / (project) / public / php -S localhost: (port)

Comment: This is such an old question, please elaborate your answer!